# Why would "svn mkdir URL" not work and "svn import ... URL" on the same URL work fine?

Tags: svn

I have a svn repository set up at

```
https://hostname/svn/repo
```

with multiple projects in it, like

```
https://hostname/svn/repo/proj_a
https://hostname/svn/repo/proj_b
https://hostname/svn/repo/proj_c
```

I can work with the existing projects without problems, I can checkout any of them, commit changes, list contents...

Now I want to create a new project in the repository, but if I try

```
svn mkdir https://hostname/svn/repo/new_project
```

on the command line I get the infamous

```
Repository moved permanently to 'https://hostname/svn/repo/'; please relocate
```

error message. Same if I try to list repository contents with `svn ls`. If instead of creating the new project folder before and adding the files later I right click the `new_project` folder in Eclipse and "share project" everything works fine. Sharing the project in Eclipse should be the equivalent of doing

```
svn import new_project https://hostname/svn/repo/new_project/trunk
```

on the command line, right? What is it I don't get? What's wrong with the repository?

**Edit** the `mkdir` command above was wrong as Álvaro G. Vicario noticed in [his reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10009242/6069)

**Update** looks like [this entry in the FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-301-error) may be related (via [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/129135/241))

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be how your Subversion ***repositories*** (yes, you could have more than one repository) are setup with Apache.

With Apache, there are two ways of setting up a Subversion repository. You can do each repository individually like this:

```
<Location /svn/repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /path/to/repositories/repos
</Location>
<Location /svn/repos2>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /path/to/repositories/repos2
</Location>
```

In this case, you could reach these repositories via `https://hostname/svn/repos` and `http://hostname/svn/repos2`.

As you can imagine, if you have oodles of repositories, it can be fairly difficult to maintain. Every time you create a new repository means updating your Apache configuration. If you have 50 or so repositories, you'd have a really long configuration file that would be tough to maintain.

To handle this, Apache allows you to configure a whole bunch of Subversion repositories in one configuration:

```
<Location /svn/repo>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /path/to/all/svn_repositories
</Location>
```

Now, if you have repositories `/path/to/all/svn_repositories/proj_a` and `/path/to/all/svn_repositories/proj_b`, you can reach them via `http://myserver/svn/repo/proj_a` and `http://myserver/svn/repo/proj_b`.

Note that `https://myserver/svn/repo` is not the root of a single repository, but the Apache *virtual* directory representing the directory that contains all of your repositories.

Now, here's the $573,198.52 question (the $64,000 question w/ inflation): If you do a commit to `http://hostname/svn/repo/proj_a`, does it update the latest revision number of `http://myserver/svn/repo/proj_b` too? If it doesn't, then each project is a separate Subversion repository and is configured as shown in my second example where multiple Subversion repositories can share the same instant.

This means that to create the `new_project`, you need to log onto your Subversion server, and use the `svnadmin create` command to create your new repository. It will then be instantly available through your `https://hostname/svn/repos/new_project` URL.

If committing changes to `proj_a` does increment the latest revision on `proj_b`, then all the projects are in a single Subversion repository, and you should be able to use `https://hostname/svn/repo` as a valid Subversion directory. Try doing a checkout:

```
$ svn co --depth=immediates https://hostname/svn/repo
```

The `--depth=immediates` will just check out the directory and not recurse through all the subdirectories. This way, you have a working directory you can use:

```
$ svn co --depth=immediates https://hostname/svn/repo
$ cd repo
$ svn mkdir --parents new_project/trunk new_project/tags new_project/branches
$ cd ..
$ svn status
A  new_project/trunk
A  new_project/tags
A  new_project/branches
$ svn commit -m "added new_project"
```

See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
             svn mkdir https://hostname/svn/     new_project
svn import new_project https://hostname/svn/repo/new_project/trunk
                                            ^^^^
```

Comment: Then I'd say your Apache is configured to send a redirect status code when you omit the trailing slash. No idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a mis-configured apache server. Server configuration was like

```
<DocumentRoot /path>
...
<Location /path/repo>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /path/repo
   ...
</Location>
```

and as the [subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-301-error) points out the document root and the repository path should not overlap.